# Create GCR secret error: exactly one NAME is required, got 26

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am trying to create a docker-registry secrete for GCR, but am getting a really cryptic error message. This is the kubectl cmd that I am running:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry gcrsecret --docker-username=_json_key --docker-password=”$(cat wk-test-1-b3c9659d9a07.json)” --docker-server=https://gcr.io --docker-email=rynslmns@gmail.com
```

But it is erroring out with the following error message:

```
error: exactly one NAME is required, got 26
```

Any thoughts? I am not seeing anything obvious in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you are using `”` (Unicode RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) instead of `"` (ASCII 0x22), which is confusing your shell.

Comment: This does not work!! I'm using this I still get the same error. kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server="https://gcr.io" --docker-username=_json_key --docker-email=you@gmail.com --docker-password="`(cat file.json)`"

Comment: The problem is that the json file contains double quotes and they have to be escaped. I couldn't figure out how to do that yet.

Answer (score 6):

Future readers.  Watch out for any spaces.

The below line will cause an error: ("BAD!")

```
kubectl create configmap special-config --from-literal=special.how=very --from-literal= special.type='charm'

error: exactly one NAME is required, got 2
```

The below line will work:

```
kubectl create configmap special-config --from-literal=special.how=very --from-literal=special.type='charm'

configmap "special-config" created
```

Note the space before "special.type" in the BAD! example.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on windows use `'` rather than `"`

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I copied and pasted the command from a browser to a terminal. Typing the code directly into the terminal solved the issue.

Comment: Solved my problem - looks like it was some special symbol

Answer (score 1):

Adding an command option which does not exist leads to the same error as well

```
kubectl create secret generic --dry-run -oj json \
mysecretname \
--from-literal=KEY=value \
| kubeseal --format yaml
```

Notice the option `j`? Remove it and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

And you cannot use `~` for set path.

`--from-file= ~/XXX` is wrong use insted `--from-file= /root/XXX`

Answer (score 0):

for windows, use git bash not powershell. Because special characters in the json file can interfere with your shell. Running in git bash solved it for me.

For linux, I do not know exactly which shell you should use, you could try using bash(the default shell terminal). Hopefully this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).